# searching array of complex objects for certain attributes and return array of values

Tags: arrays, object

I am trying to search through an array of complex objects and find a certain attributes who's value I want to collect in a flat array.

I tried already many methods, but none of them seems to work.

I have an array like this, and I want to find all the ccc-values, but only the ccc-attributes that are part of 'bbb'-object,

```
let arr = [
        { aaa: { bbb: { ccc: 11 } } },
        { aaa: { bbb: { eee: { ccc: 12 } } } },
        { aaa: { bbb: 101} },
        { },
        { aaa: { bbb: { ccc: 511 } } },
        { aaa: { bbb: { ccc: 77 } } },
        { aaa: 24 },
        { aaa: { bbb: { ccc: {ddd: 11 } } } },
]
```

The latest test I tried this code, which is not working:

```
function traverse(obj) {
    const objEntries = Object.entries(obj)
    if (objEntries.length === 0) {
        return 0
    } else {
        const [key, value] = objEntries[0]
        if (key === "bbb") {
            const [key, value] = objEntries[0]
            if (key === "ccc" && typeof (value) === "number") {
                return value
            } else if (typeof (value) === "number") {
                return 0
            }
        return traverse(value)
        }
    }
}

let result = [];
let arr = msg.arr;

arr.forEach(a => {
    result.push(traverse(a))
})

msg.payload = result;
```

I expect an array with a result like this

result = [11, 0, 0, 0, 511, 77, 0, 0]

Comment: Is this in any language in particular, and if so, which one?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every object has only one key, you could do a basic recursion like this:

```js
let arr = [{
    aaa: {
      bbb: {
        ccc: 11
      }
    }
  },
  {
    aaa: {
      bbb: {
        eee: {
          ccc: 12
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    aaa: {
      bbb: 101
    }
  },
  {},
  {
    aaa: {
      bbb: {
        ccc: 511
      }
    }
  },
  {
    aaa: {
      bbb: {
        ccc: 77
      }
    }
  },
  {
    aaa: 24
  },
  {
    aaa: {
      bbb: {
        ccc: {
          ddd: 11
        }
      }
    }
  },
]

let result = []

function traverse(obj, searchKey = "", searchParentKey = "", previousKey = "") {
  const objEntries = Object.entries(obj)
  if (objEntries.length === 0) {
    return 0
  } else {
    const [key, value] = objEntries[0]

    if (key === searchKey && typeof(value) === "number" && previousKey === searchParentKey) {
      return value
    } else if (typeof(value) === "number") {
      return 0
    }

    return traverse(value, searchKey, searchParentKey, key)
  }
}

arr.forEach(a => {
  result.push(traverse(a, "ccc", "bbb"))
})

console.log(result)
```

EDIT: added previousKey and searchKey

Comment: This is exactly what I mean, thanks very much, I can even understand what is happening in the function.  :)

Comment: You are right, but I am afraid that the solution was not perfect for my project. It turns out that only the ccc-attributes that are located in 'bbb' are valid values for me. I tried altering the routine, but didn,t get it right. So I changed the array a bit.

Comment: Is it also possible to have a variable for the search-string added to the function, so the function is more universal. I tried this already, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I can't seem to add your name in the post, I use at-sign + your name, but after saving the comment, it disappears.???

Comment: @Henkkas updated, added rule "parent must be bbb"